# ASP.NET MVC 5 using DateTime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project for an Event application. My task is to create a partial view and show any events that are within the next two days.

I am getting an error:

> Operator <= cannot be applied to operands of type string and DateTime

I am unsure how to fix this issue.

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult GetLastMinuteDeals()
{
    DateTime futureDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2);

    var LastMinuteDeal = db.Events
                           .Where(a => a.EventStartDate <= DateTime.Today)
                           .Where(a => a.EventStartDate <= futureDate);
    return LastMinuteDeal;
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. What about it do you not understand? What type is EventStartDate?

Comment: Obviously you are trying to compare an object of type ‘DateTime’ with an object of type ‘String’. Since DateTime.Today is an object of DateTime, the attribute ‘EventStartDate’ has to be a string. Store the EventStartDate as DateTime or parse it to DateTime.

Comment: EventStartDate is a String type. I wasn't sure how to correct this issue. @mason

Comment: Change the declaration of that property to be of type DateTime.

Answer (score -1):

The member `EventStartDate` is likely a `string` type. To compare them to a `DateTime`, you will need to create another `DateTime` object, like so:

```
var LastMinuteDeal = db.Events
            .Where(a => DateTime.Parse(a.EventStartDate) <= DateTime.Today)
            .Where(a => DateTime.Parse(a.EventStartDate) <= futureDate);
```

Comment: It would be far more beneficial to change the type of EventStartDate rather than littering the code with Datetime.Parse.

Comment: Assuming the asker has access to the change the class definition, then yes, that is correct.